# Updating state in reactjs is repeating my code infinite - React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I am creating prayer times web app in `reactJS (nextjs)`, for that, i am first fetching geolocation coordinates and then i am getting city and country name by coordinates and then I am getting prayer times by city and country. I wanna show timings in my html (under the return function) and for that i am storing the timings in a state variable, and when i am updating the state variable with prayer timings, it is repeating my code again and again, it means, my api requests are repeating infinite. I don't know what is happening.
**Here is my code:**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"

const HomeHeader = () => {

    const [loading, updateLoadingStatus] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                getCoordinates,
                handleGeolocationErrors
            );
        } else {
            console.log('Geolocation is not supported in this browser');
        }
    });

    return (
        <header className="header">
            {/* Timings Html here */}
        </header>
    )
}

export default HomeHeader
```

Can someone help me to get rid of this repeating thing? Why it is even repeating the code? I am stuck

Comment: try adding empty dependency array in your useEffect call like this `useEffect(()=> {},[])`. - adding empty array means you are calling your function just once on component mount, it will then behave like componentDidMount of class component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Add an empty square braces at the end.
It will behave same as ComponentDidMount life cycle hook in Class based components

```
useEffect(() => {
        if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                getCoordinates,
                handleGeolocationErrors
            );
        } else {
            console.log('Geolocation is not supported in this browser');
        }
    },[]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever use useEffect without any dependency your useEffect update continusly

Give an square brace as dependency to your useEffect

```
   useEffect(() => {
        if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                getCoordinates,
                handleGeolocationErrors
            );
        } else {
            console.log('Geolocation is not supported in this browser');
        }
    }, []);
```